# Parsing stack-trace of a crash

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, stack-trace

In one of my apps I have a very common crash.
I have this report in bugsense : `*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array`

And this stack trace after symbolication:

```
0 CoreFoundation 0x3796b2a3 + 162
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x3546b97f objc_exception_throw + 30
2 CoreFoundation 0x378b6b75 + 164
3 CoreData 0x357d9c93 + 1202
4 CoreData 0x357da863 + 1858
5 CoreFoundation 0x378bc037 _CFXNotificationPost + 1426
6 Foundation 0x39992d91 + 72
7 CoreData 0x35768307 + 78
8 CoreData 0x35767867 + 298
9 CoreData 0x356e9c0b + 2698
10 CoreData 0x356e910f + 270
11 CoreFoundation 0x379406cd + 20
12 CoreFoundation 0x3793e9c1 + 276
13 CoreFoundation 0x3793ed17 + 742
14 CoreFoundation 0x378b1ebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
15 CoreFoundation 0x378b1d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
16 GraphicsServices 0x355672eb GSEventRunModal + 74
17 UIKit 0x37329301 UIApplicationMain + 1120
18 HiBye 0x000c579d main + 244
19 libdyld.dylib 0x36207b20 + 0
```

I understand that the problem is in an empty `NSMutableArray` but I can not locate the place or at least a potential place in the code. I know that this trace does not say to much but I will appreciate any idea or direction that you can get from it that I might not be aware of.

Thanks
Shani

Comment: Have you enabled Exception Breakpoints in your application ?

Comment: YES, but this is a user crash from production app. Why?

Comment: Please try to symbolicate this crash report. Seems like it's not symbolicated. Symbolication will help you in find the line of code.